# Date format Conversion with IntlDateFormatter

Tags: php, laravel-5

In one of my form I've got a date datepicker element where the user can enter a date :

```
datepicker format is D d MM yyyy
```

When the form is saved I would like to save the date into the right format :

```
Y-m-d
```

In my Laravel Controller, I have a Hook Method which enable me to manipulate data before saved into the table.

The code I wrote to manipulate the format of my date works in http://www.writephponline.com :

```
$deliverydate = 'Di. 24 Mars 2019'; // Mer. 23 Janvier 2019 OK

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$formatter->setPattern('eee dd MMMM y');
$formatter_parse = $formatter->parse($deliverydate);
$deliverydate_formatted = date('Y-m-d', $formatter_parse);

var_dump($deliverydate_formatted);
```

and return the correct value :

```
string(10) "2019-03-24"
```

but not in Laravel which return me :

```
1970-01-01
```

No clue why. Would appreciate your expertise. Cheers, Marc

Comment: Did you try Carbon ?$input  = '11/06/1990';$format = 'd/m/Y';$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $input);

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, tried with carbon but followring error id generated:

1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found